# Forward specific port of a domain.com:1234 to different IP

Tags: dns, port, forward

my domain "https://example.com forwards to my webserver IP eg "0.0.0.1".

Is it possible that when I call the domain like "tcp://example.com:1234" to forward the request to a different IP like "0.0.0.2:1234"? Or is the only way to use a subdomain?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It's about a self-host or a shared host on a service provider?

**If it's a self-host:**
Someone receives your internet connection, in the business environment we usually use a firewall, so you just need to create/configure (on the firewall) your "nat rules" to work as you need with specific ports and IP.

**If it's a service provider:**
You must do check if they allow nat configuration (can be called port forward or publish rules)